# Install Ubuntu by hard disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive

I have a Windows 10 and I want to install Ubuntu 18.04.1 beside it. (I want to have two OSs).

My PC has two hard disks and I want to install Ubuntu on Disk 1 --> Drive: Ubuntu(U:). Here are my partitions:

[image: my partitions]

My PC doesn't have any CD/DVD-ROM and I can't install by USB so my only choice is to install it by the hard disk.

I tried **UNetbootin** but it only detects the (C:) drive and doesn't detect (U:) drive which I want to install Ubuntu on it. Here is the picture: 
[image: picture of UNetbootin]

What's wrong? How can I install it on the (U:) drive just by the hard disk?

Comment: Just curious, how did you install windows if without USB or the option to boot through USB?

Comment: @Albin by USB before it gets ruined :))

Comment: Use grub for booting from .iso file.

Comment: I can tell you a few things that you probably aren't aware of but should if you want to dive into the world of Linux: (1) Drive letters are for Windows only; (2) Do not create partitions in Windows for Ubuntu as it's a waste of time - Linux can't be installed in NTFS partitions and the file systems required for Linux can't be created in Windows so just leave unallocated space instead and the installer will take care of creating the partitions it needs; (3) Not sure Unetbootin can be used the way you want.

Comment: It might be more straightforward to ask to borrow someone's optical drive and a burned Ubuntu 18.04 DVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use, for example, a 3rd party bootloader like Grub4Dos to install Ubuntu without using external media. [Here's a detail description on how to do it](http://agnipulse.com/2011/08/install-ubuntu-hard-disk/). But you will need space on one of you're hard drives to create a partition for the Ubuntu installation. You can not install in you're existing NTFS partition.

An alternative would be to create a virtual machine within your windows an install you're Ubuntu within the virtual machine. You could use for example VirtualBox or VMplayer they are both free. There are "ready to use" installations you can download too, so you don't need to go through the Ubuntu installation process at all.

**Here's a short explanation on how to install Ubuntu from ISO using Grub4Dos**

- [Install Grub4dos to your Hard Disk](http://agnipulse.com/2010/06/install-grub4dos-hard-disk/).
- Download Ubuntu (the iso image) to the root of any drive.
- Add the following entry to menu.lst

Entries:

```
title Install Ubuntu   
find --set-root /ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso    
map /ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso (0xff)  || map --mem /ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso (0xff)    
map --hook    
root (0xff)    
kernel /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed noprompt boot=casper only-ubiquity iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.iso quiet splash --    
initrd /casper/initrd.lz
```

- Reboot and choose Install Ubuntu in the Grub4dos menu.
- After the live desktop loads, open terminal and enter the following command.

Command:

```
sudo umount -l /isodevice
```

- Now double click on Install Ubuntu.You should be able to install Ubuntu